# Why should we use stack, since an array or linked list can do everything a stack can do

Tags: arrays, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I was wondering why should we even use stack, since an array or linked list can do everything a stack can do? Why do we bother name it a "data structure" separately? In the real world, just use an array would be sufficient enough to solve the problem; why would one bother to implement a stack which will restrict himself to only be able to push and pop from the top of the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to use the term *data type* to refer to things whose behavior is defined by some interface, or algebra, or collection of operations.  Things like

- stacks
- queues
- priority queues
- dequeues
- lists
- sets
- hierarchies
- maps (dictionaries)

are types because for each, we just list their behaviors.  Stacks are stacks because they can only be pushed and popped.  Queues are queues because ... (you get the picture).

On the other hand, a *data structure* is an implementation of a data type defined by the way it arranges its components.  Examples include

- array (constant time access by index)
- linked list
- bitmap
- BSTs
- Red-black tree
- (a,b)-trees (e.g. 2-3 trees)
- Skip lists
- hash tables (many variants)
- adjacency matrices
- Bloom filters
- Judy arrays
- Tries

A lot of people do confuse the terms data structures and data types, but it's best not to be too pedantic.  Stacks are data types, not data structures, but again, why be too pedantic.

To answer your specific question, we use stacks as data types in situations where we want to ensure or data is modified only by pushing and popping and we never violate this access pattern (even by accident).

Under the hoodm we may use a linked list as an implementation of our stack.  But most programming languages will provide a way to *restrict* the interface to allow our code to readably, and securely, use our data in a LIFO fashion.

TL;DR: Readability. Security.

Answer (score 1):

Stacks can and usually are implemented using an array or a linked list as the underlying structure. There are many benefits to using a Stack.

One of the main benefits is the LIFO ordering that is maintained by the push/pop operations. This allows for the stack elements to have a natural order and be removed from the stack in the reverse order to the order of their addition. Such data structure can be very useful in many applications where using just an array or a linked list would actually be less efficient and/or more complicated. Some of those applications are:

- Balancing of symbols (such as parenthesis)
- Infix-to-postfix conversion
- Evaluation of postfix expression
- Implementing function calls (including recursion)
- Finding of spans (finding spans in stock markets)
- Page-visited history in a Web browsed (Back buttons)
- Undo sequence in a text editor
- Matching Tags in HTML and XML

[**`Here are some more stack applications`**](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/Stacks_and_Queues#Applications_of_Stacks)

[**`And some more...`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)#Applications)

The two underlying implementations of an array or a linked list give the stack different capabilities and features. Here is a simple comparison:

**(Dynamic) Array Implementation:**

```
1. All operations take constant time besides push().
2. Expensive doubling operation every once in a while.
3. Any sequence of n operations (starting from empty stack) -> "amortized" bound takes time proportional to n.
```

**Linked List Implementation:**

```
1. Grows and shrinks easily.
2. Every operation takes constant time O(1).
3. Every operation uses extra space and time to deal with references.
```